Is there a way to search like CTRL+F in Gerbers or a PCB picture to find a specific part?
Is there any way to search for a component with the new AI advancement in image text search?
When I am looking for a part, I typically search through the silkscreen or the PCB itself, until I find it. This is time-consuming, very annoying, and shockingly inefficient.
Given I have the pick and place data, it should be possible to match it with the Gerber data, or an image of the PCB.

are you looking for something like "find U17"?  What data/file formats do you have?

yes exactly. I usually get regular Gerber files and Pick and pick/place data.

What format is the pick and place data?

the format is  .txt with the x y location and the name of the part

If you've already got x-y location and the name of the part in a text file, what exactly are you after?  Why can't you search that file?

No. Neither Gerbers nor pictures contain that data.
Pick and place data usually only contains "position" "part (model) number", not "designator" (like "U17") to "position", as that's irrelevant to the pick & place machine.
Some extended formats might, but you'd really need to work with the specific tooling for these formats, then.

Is there any way to search for a component with the NEW AI advancement in image text search?

Oh someone's been feeding you AI nonsense. Great. We've had OCR that would be good enough to read silkscreen standardized fonts for about 40 years. We didn't call it "AI", because, like modern "AI", nothing is intelligent about it. It's character recognition. Nobody, to my knowledge, just took an OCR engine and threw it specifically at Gerbers – but there's hundreds of frontends that you can use to OCR text in images. This is nothing new, and so unspecific that software recommendations for that are off-topic for this site.
It would be a pretty nice beginner's exercise if you took an open source OCR engine (say, tesseract), and used it specifically with a gerber renderer (say, gerbv). Should really not be much code to go from gerber of silkscreen to list of silkscreen positions!
But the hard part is that where the silkscreen text is, is by definition not where the component sits. That's probably a harder task, and it will vary very much with annotation style of the board layouter.
How will you do the following matching without a lot of human experience or copious amounts of labeled data?

PCB silkscreen pattern Reference designator arrangement on a dense PCB in the top overlay layer. Source: altium.com: "PCB Silkscreen Guidelines"
That is how one designer thinks is easy to read. Frankly, I disagree, and do it differently. I'm sure people doing more work in the field of board layouts will have even different styles!

i have heard of tesseract but no idea how to use it. I am willing to learn and make something out of it. can you guide me to some resources i can start with.

I would have to type tesseract OCR engine into a search engine, then look up the project homepage, avoid any third party youtube videos or blog pages, look for the documentation on the project homepage, and then look for things like "Getting started" or "usage examples" or something. Same as you. So, you can well do that 2minutes of research yourself!

I see, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Some of the later Gerber specification does include component designators (%TO.C) but much CAD doesn't output it.  But OP already has X-Y-ID place data, so neither OCR nor Gerber extraction is required.

@jonathanjo yeah, I just saw the comment. I frankly was assuming that was not available, being the literal answer to the question.

right now I am using the XY location to locate the components but I always do not have access to xy location sometimes its just .csv file with just designators.
The origin of the (0,0) sometimes are in different corners which makes that location useless sometimes.

No OCR is required.
If you've already got x-y location and the name of the part in a text file, what exactly are you after?
Consider using a ready-made tool to make images (say PNGs) of the Gerber files: such as gerbv -xpng ... (manpage).
Then you write a script (python or shell) which joins the PNGs with the placement data and produces a PDF.  You view the PDF in Acrobat or whatever, and can certainly search with Ctrl-F exactly as you describe.
Alternatively, consider adding Ctrl-F functionality to Gerbv by importing your X-Y-Ident file; but this would be a lot harder.

thank you a lot i will try this as well.

ya, the problem sometime is that (0,0) coordinates sometimes are in different corners which makes that location useless sometimes.

Respectfully, it's a lot easier to help you if you shows us what exact kind of information you actually have.  Please edit your question with some actual examples of the data you have.  In any case, converting origins is a much, much simpler problem than OCR, and so would be a lot easier to do and a lot more reliable.

I would say it's not ready yet. I gave ChatGPT-4o an image of the silk-screen layer of a non-trivial PCB design (more than 100 components, with logos and such like), and a .csv list of designators and it was not able to find them in the image. It is capable of parsing the Gerber directly, but not making sense of it.

Despite enhancing the image with contrast adjustments and thresholding, the OCR process still didn’t match any of the designators from the CSV file. This could indicate that the OCR engine is struggling with the specific font or layout in the Gerber image.
If you'd like, we can try alternative OCR engines, different image
processing techniques, or explore manual methods for detecting these
elements. Let me know how you’d like to proceed! ​

.. and I've run out of patience.
One way to do this starting from EDA tools is to generate a .pdf format file, which may well be searchable depending on how your tools work. Of course it's also possible to generate stupid .pdf files that are not searchable because the the characters of (say) a designator are not grouped together, but rather splattered onto the image like individual unrelated elements.
There are some quite interesting tools from a technician point of view that are used in servicing things like smart phones. Here is  one (I've not tried it personally)- it would be nice to be able to do something like that to make service and rework easier. I see something about it working with KiCad and maybe that Autodesk thing that used to be popular.

I put a gerber viewer screengrab into Google image search, and the OCR worked work and the overall effect was amusing but useless.

@jonathanjo Google seems to have trouble grokking text if the text is upside-down or sideways.

thank you @Spehro'speff'Pefhany. I love to see your thoughts on so many topics here in EE stack. I will try doing that with other OCR engines. i will le you know what i come up with

I've tried OCR on a PDF editor program on old assembly documents and it couldn't recognize text that was rotated or tiny. Perhaps the boxes surrounding the text caused problems.
If you use ODB++ PCB output, the assembly text is searchable in a ODB++ viewer program. This gives the added ability to follow traces connected to the component of interest.
Modern design tools can create schematics and PCB assembly drawings in PDF format where the reference designators are searchable. The example below is a snippet from a PDF output from Altium Draftsman using a third party PDF printer (Altium's PDF generator doesn't function well with text). The small resistors & capacitors are 0402 size. R17 is highlighted from a search operation.
The broader scope of my assembly documents shows component locations for the top & bottom of the board, a shortened bill of materials (for technician & engineering use), 3D rendered images, along with any special assembly instructions. All pertinent text is searchable.

Source: self
